# RunTime Analysis Big O

Tags: runtime, big-o

I was wondering if the runtime analysis is true for O(n^2) is it also true for O (n^3) and vice versa? I got a runtime for one problem O (n^3) and someone got O (n^2). But she said it could be both

Comment: Hi Dana, 
You're question is quite vague, please provide some examples with your question (i.e. the problem). Also, there's a distinction between the time complexity of a specific solution vs. the optimal solution to a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If someone else worked on the same problem as you and determined that the running time is `O(n^2)`, then by definition `O(n^3)` is also a bound to the same problem.  Your problem, if the other person be correct, is that the `O(n^3)` bound you are reporting is not the tightest bound which can be given.  Actually, it is pretty far from the tightest bound.

In general, the tightest bound is what we want to report for an algorithm or running time, because that tells us how much computing power we might need to solve the problem.  So, you should review your answer and try to see if you can also get the `O(n^2)` bound.